# Audio Recording not smooth and continuous

Tags: android, service, audio-recording

Please help me to figure out that i am recording sound .

1. I want to record via service which produces jerks in sound while recording.I have buttons in activity from where i Start Recording and Stop Recording.
2. The Same code work absolutely fine if i do in activity.

The Service i am providing below

public class ServiceMusic  extends Service {
    private static String LOG_TAG = "BoundService";

```
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
private static ServiceMusic self = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onCreate");
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    Log.i("onStartComman?d", "onStartCommand"); 
    self = ServiceMusic.this;
    self.bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    self.recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    TelephonyManager mgr=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr!=null) 
    {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}


@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onRebind");
    super.onRebind(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onUnbind");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "in onDestroy");
    //  mChronometer.stop();
}


private String getFilename(){
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Ravindra" + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}

private String getTempFilename(){
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if(tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

void startRecording(final boolean b){

    if (self.recorder==null) {
        //Log.i("startRecording", "iffffffffffffffffffff");

        self.recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    }
    self.recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    self.recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile(b);
        }
    },"AudioRecorder Thread");

    self.recordingThread.start();
}

void stopRecording(boolean b){
    Log.i("stopRecording", "stopRecording");
    if(self.recorder != null){
        isRecording = false;

        self.recorder.stop();
        self.recorder.release();

        self.recorder = null;
        self.recordingThread = null;
        Log.i("stopRecording", "nulll");

    }
    Log.i("stopRecording", "outer");

    if(b == true){
        Log.i("stopRecording", "true");

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
        deleteTempFile();
    }
}

private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());

    file.delete();
}
private void writeAudioDataToFile(boolean b){
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename,b);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int read = 0;

    if(os != null){
        while(isRecording){
            read = self.recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}  

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 44;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 44;

        //AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while(in.read(data) != -1){
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acquire a wakelock when you start recording, and release it when you stop. Otherwise the device may go to sleep.  For an example, see line 820 onwards of the android sound recorder app https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/SoundRecorder/+/master/src/com/android/soundrecorder/SoundRecorder.java
(You may consider using a partial wake lock instead of a screen dim wake lock in the code above, if you are running in a background service)

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html